# Kivy garden graph opacity animation

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to make MeshLinePlot of kivy_garden Graph fade in using animation tool in kivy. As far as I understand the only way to make the line transparent is to set alpha parameter in color property of MeshLinePlot equal to 0. It works, but only for some small parts of the line. And I need to make transparent the whole line. I have found nothing on the internet to help me. Here is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App
import numpy as np
from math import sin, sqrt, exp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy_garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot, SmoothLinePlot
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.animation import Animation


class myApp(App):
    lbl=Label(text="0", size_hint_y=0.3)

    S0=50
    mu=0.05
    sig=0.3
    dt=1/365



    graph=Graph(
                    xmin=0, 
                    xmax=50, 
                    ymin=0, 
                    ymax=100, 
                    x_ticks_major=50,
                    y_ticks_major=10,
                    tick_color=[0.06,0.06,0.06,1],
                    draw_border=False,
                    x_grid=True,
                    y_grid=True
    )



    plot2 = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
    first_point=(0,50) 
    plot2.points=[first_point]
    graph.add_plot(plot2)
    event=None
    St=S0

    def on_start(self):
        self.event=Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_plot, 1/60)

    def build(self):
        bl=BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        bl.add_widget(self.lbl)
        bl.add_widget(self.graph)
        return bl

    def update_plot(self, *ARGS):
        drift=(self.mu-self.sig*self.sig*0.5)*self.dt
        epsilon=np.random.normal()
        var=epsilon*self.sig*sqrt(self.dt)
        self.St=self.St*exp(drift+var)
        last_x2=self.plot2.points[len(self.plot2.points)-1][0]
        new_point2=(last_x2+1, self.St)
        self.plot2.points.append(new_point2)
        self.lbl.text=str(last_x2)
        if last_x2+1==self.graph.xmax:
            Clock.unschedule(self.event)
            self.lbl.text=str("Clocking stopped")
            anim=Animation(color=[1, 0, 0, 0.0])  #<-- problem here
            anim.start(self.plot2)
        

myApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the entire graph transparent by setting its `opacity` to `0`:

```
graph.opacity = 0
```

Then in your `update_plot()` method, you can animate that opacity:

```
        anim = Animation(opacity=1, duration=5)  # <-- problem here
        anim.start(self.graph)
```